# svg to canvas image in jspdf - I Get a black content

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, jspdf

> I've used jspdf to convert the svg image to canvas and then to pdf
>
> > The plugins I've used are
> >
> > > ```
> > > <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
> > > <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jspdf.js"></script>
> > > <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
> > > <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/html2canvas.svg.js"></script>
> > > <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/canvg.js"></script>
> > > ```
>
> My HTML code for the svg is

```
<a href="javascript:genPdf();">genpdf</a>

<svg class="bullet" width="416" height="50">
    <g transform="translate(75,5)">
        <rect class="range s0" width="301" height="25" x="0"/>
        <rect class="range s1" width="250.83333333333334" height="25" x="0"/>
        <rect class="range s2" width="200.66666666666666" height="25" x="0"/>
        <rect class="measure s0" width="230.76666666666668" height="8.333333333333334" x="0" y="8.333333333333334"/>
        <rect class="measure s1" width="210.7" height="8.333333333333334" x="0" y="8.333333333333334"/>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line y1="25" y2="29.166666666666668"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="29.166666666666668">0</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(50.16666793823242,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line y1="25" y2="29.166666666666668"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="29.166666666666668">5</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(100.33333587646484,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line y1="25" y2="29.166666666666668"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="29.166666666666668">10</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(150.5,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line y1="25" y2="29.166666666666668"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="29.166666666666668">15</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(200.6666717529297,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line y1="25" y2="29.166666666666668"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="29.166666666666668">20</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(250.8333282470703,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line y1="25" y2="29.166666666666668"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="29.166666666666668">25</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(301,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
            <line y1="25" y2="29.166666666666668"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" dy="1em" y="29.166666666666668">30</text>
        </g>
        <g x="200" y="100" style="text-anchor: end;" transform="translate(-6,12.5)">
            <text class="title">NOVORA</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

> I'm unable to get the exact image that is required as an output when I generate it to pdf.
>   I'm converting the svg to canvas but still I'm unable to get the desired output. Instead of the exact image I get a black content inside that.
>   The css code for the above one is

```
.bullet {
    font: 10 px sans-serif;
}
.bullet.marker {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.bullet .tick line {
    stroke: # 666;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}
.bullet.range.s0 {
    fill: #eee;
}
.bullet.range.s1 {
    fill: #ddd;
}
.bullet.range.s2 {
    fill: #ccc;
}
.bullet.measure.s0 {
    fill: steelblue;
}
.bullet.measure.s1 {
    fill: #fff;
}
.bullet.measure.s2 {
    fill: steelblue;
}
.bullet.measure.s3 {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
}
.bullet.title {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.bullet.subtitle {
    fill: #999;
}
```

> The javascript that helps me rendering the data is

```
function genPdf(){
    var svgElements = $("#page-content-wrapper").find('svg');

      //replace all svgs with a temp canvas
    svgElements.each(function() {
        var canvas, xml;

        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.className = "screenShotTempCanvas";
        // canvas.getContext("3d");
        //convert SVG into a XML string
        xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this);

        // Removing the name space as IE throws an error
        xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');

        //draw the SVG onto a canvas
        canvg(canvas, xml);
        $(canvas).insertAfter(this);
        $(this).addClass('tempHide');
        $(this).hide();
    });
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('page-content-wrapper'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas){
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG' , 10, 10);
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#page-content-wrapper").find('.screenShotTempCanvas').remove();
        $("#page-content-wrapper").find('.tempHide').show().removeClass('tempHide');
        $("#page-content-wrapper").find('.bullet').show();
    },2000);
}

function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
    var camelize = function(str) {
        return str.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });
    };

    if (el.currentStyle) {
        return el.currentStyle[camelize(styleProp)];
    } else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)
        .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    } else {
        return el.style[camelize(styleProp)];
    }
}
```

> Please help me out in this. Thanks

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Are you sure your CSS is working? Fiddle with your example shows all black bar http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/164/

Comment: Maybe this fixed CSS is what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/165/

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle but I don't know how to add the js as I don't have cdn for external js
https://jsfiddle.net/debjeet/hw4yyf9r/

Comment: I've got the solution. I've called the css from javascript and it works